# Twitter Cards now woring with PHP script?

Tags: php, twitter-card

**Update**

```
<?PHP
    $Title = "This is the Open Grah script";
    $Description = "This is the one and only Description, or better yeh the first 150 charecters of the main content on your page. What ever you feel like really!";
    $Twitter = "@obama";

     echo "<html>
            <head>
             <title> $Title </title>";
     echo '<meta name="description" content=" ';
     echo $Description;
     echo '" />';

     echo "<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />";  
     echo '<meta name="twitter:site" content"';
     echo $Twitter
     echo '"/>';
     echo '<meta name="twitter:title" content"';
     echo $Title;
     echo '" />';
     echo '<meta name="twitter:description" content" ';
     echo $Description;
     echo '" />';

    ?>
```

Following up on my last question, my page won't load at all anymore, I'm sorry if you feel like im wasting peoples time. It is probably just a typo.

Comment: Also - try to avoid wrapping HTML in PHP, it puts unessesary pressure on the server, do something like: 
`if (true) 
{ ?>
<h1>True</h1>
 <?php  } else { ?> 
<h1>False</h1> 
<?php  }`

Comment: yes i know but how would that work with this script if you get what i mean?

Comment: You have, as mentioned in answers below, used `echo "<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />";`, if you left this in the PHP,  you'd have to escape the quotes inside the quotes else you get errors, if you "unwrap" the HTML, you do not have to worry about escaping the special characters and it means it's a lot safer for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 echo "<meta name='twitter:card' content='summary' />";
```

You need to make sure that you're not using `"` inside the string that you start with `"`. You should either use `'` or `\"` inside your string starting with `"`.

Two lines after that you're missing `;`.

```
echo $Twitter;
```